# Salesforce Marketing Cloud SSO setting with OpenID Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, open-id-connect

I'm trying to set up Marketing cloud Single-sign-on. I'm not allowed to use SAML.
I'll need to config the SSO via Open Id Connect.

Is there anyone can give me some idea how to do it?

---

Just quick update for the question.

The idea is like below:

Client OIDC->OIDC transfer to SAML connector ->connector send SAML to SFMC

So here's what I think the process shall be:

1. get the connector (which I have found 3 of them, search what the best for your case)
2. config customer's OIDC in the connector
3. config the connector in SFMC SSO

If anyone test it please feel free to share any update with me.

Comment: Note: We are using third party as IdP, SFMC as SP.

Comment: Just quick update for the question.

I have found other connector that is able to transform OIDC to SAML, in this case it's able to design SSO to login SFMC.

Thanks again for Macca's help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Vee, can you share which connector are using to transform OIDC to SAML? We are looking at integrating OpenID Connect with SFMC too. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Kaon, the one I've found is Onelogin. HOWEVER, not sure will it work or not. I had seek for their advice and according to them, it's possible to achieve it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Marketing Cloud doesn't support OpenID Connect. SSO is only possible using SFMC's [SAML 2.0 implementation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_single_sign_on_authentication_via_saml_2.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you Macca!